# Получить статьи по ID категории в определенном формате

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

Здравствуйте, у меня появилось 3 вопроса в плане PHP, MySQL и Yii2. 
Сами вопросы в конце, а пока детали задачи.

Итак, мы имеем 2 таблицы: *categorie_id* и *articles*.

article_categories - категории статей и их описание.
articles - статьи.

[image: структура ДБ]

Я хочу реализовать так, чтобы на выходе иметь ассоциативный массив такого плана:

```
[categorie_id]=>
        [article],
        [article],
        [article]
```

### Приведу живой пример:

**Имеем категории:**

```
Рыбы[ID:1],
Млекопитающие[ID:2]
```

**Имеем статьи:**

```
Кенгуру[Categorie_ID:2],
Акула[Categorie_ID:1],
Карась[Categorie_ID:1],
Пёс[Categorie_ID:2],
Медведь[Categorie_ID:2],
Скат[Categorie_ID:1]
```

И я хочу, чтобы по запросу мы имели массив следующей структуры:

```
[1]=>
    [
        'title' => 'Акула'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Карась'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Скат'
    ]
[2]=>
    [
        'title' => 'Кенгуру'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Пёс'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Медведь'
    ]
```

Собственно, я реализовал код, но я беспокоюсь за его правильность и правильно ли вовсе обрабатывать эти данные в PHP? Возможно, есть возможность это сделать прямо в MySQL?
Я попытался "поиграться" с JOIN'ами - но не вышло, увы.

Поэтому, реализовал такое решение:

/*
$articles - все статьи в ассоциативном массиве 
$articles_category - все категории и их описание в ассоциативном массиве
*/

```
$data = []; 
for($i = 0; $i < count($articles_category); $i++){
    for($a = 0; $a < count($articles); $a++){
        if($articles[$a]['articles_category'] == $articles_category[$i]['id']){
            $data[$i][] = [
                "title" => $articles[$a]['title'],
                "description" => $articles[$a]['description']
            ];
            // ... и другие столбцы
        }
    }
}
```

### И у меня 3 вопроса: ##

1. Возможно ли провернуть такое в MySQL, чтобы сразу на выходе иметь данные в указанном выше формате?
2. Если нет или это нецелесобразно: всё ли ОК в нынешнем коде? Возможно, его можно как-то оптимизировать?
3. Сам сейчас работаю под Yii2, и интересовался у знакомого по этому вопросу и он говорил, что есть метод в Yii2, который сам производит подобное переобразование, вроде как. Это правда? Если да, не подскажите этот метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на 2 и 3 вопрос сразу. В коде выше не всё ок, слишком много лишних иттераций по моему там выполняется, и в Yii2 есть [ArrayHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html) с помощью которого можно всё красиво сделать, попробуйте следующий код:

```
$articles = Articles::find()->all(); // Добавляете свои условия если надо

$data = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($articles, 'id', function($model) {
    return [
        'title' => $model->title,
        'description' => $model->description,
        //остальные ваши поля, в $model лежит объект AR с данными
    ];
}, 'categorie_id');
```

И на выходе вы получите то что хотели, только выполняться всё будет куда быстрее и выглядеть лучше.

Вот вариант в котором нам нужно добавлять информацию как на этом скрине:
[image: пример]

```
//Исходные данные:
//$articles_category - Надеюсь это у вас массив категорий

$data = [];
foreach ($articles_category as $category) {
    $data[$category->id]['categorie_name'] = $category->title;
    //Обращаемся к реляции записей под названием articles к примеру
    $data[$category->id]['articles'] = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($category->articles, 'id', function($model) {
        return [
            'title' => $model->title,
            'description' => $model->description,
            //остальные ваши поля, в $model лежит объект AR с данными
        ];
    });
}

var_dump($data); //Должен вывести всё такое же как на срине
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Хм, а что если, к примеру, нужно усложнить задачу и получать ещё данные по категориям, которые хранятся в таблице services_categories? Т.е. иметь на выходе массив такого типа: https://pastebin.com/zyM7iwLT (скрин: http://savepic.org/8623429.png). Заранее спасибо Вам :)

Comment: Ну тогда средства Yii не помогут, нужно будет свой цикл foreach делать

Comment: Цикл, который в примере в шапке вопроса, для этого подойдет или всё же ещё не то и нужно поработать над оптимизацией?

Comment: Частично переписывать его надо, обновил ответ

Comment: Хм, насколько я понял, в Вашем примере работа с одной таблицей(ибо мне выбивает ошибку об Unknown Proprery "article")

Статьи хранятся в таблице articles,,а вот категории и их описание - article_categorys.

Надеюсь, на этот я раз нормально объяснил :)